# How to add existing items (from web) to a project in visual studio using hyperlinks?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to add existing files from a hosted/published Sharepoint library to my Visual Studio-Solution using hyperlinks or references.

I tried to open the library in File Explorer and browse the files in the open existing item dialog in VS using library-path but VS can't open the path or it opens it but doesn't add the files.

Is that possible? Can i add Refrences/Links to files, which are hosted in Web?

Comment: Probably not. Connecting to WebDAV folders is a feature of Windows Explorer, not a lower-level VFS feature. (Like connecting to SMB shares is.) I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't really possible to handle files consistently to local ones. If you have an up-to-date Sharepoint installation you can use SkyDrive Pro and sync the library locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Anyway, you should only have references in your solution that refer to stable resources. Links  are subject to link rot and/or network issues, which widely opens the door for a variety of serious difficulties.